How to correct for electron capture in the rate of neutron decay?
Inspired by this question asking if the free neutron decay discrepancy has been resolved yet.
I was doing a little bit of research to find some references for an answer to that - it turns out we still don’t know as late as 2021 - and began wondering: is it possible that, in the beam-method measurement, electron capture by protons (once neutrons) is more likely so that decayed neutrons have a higher chance to “revert” in the beam method vs. the bottle method?
My reasoning (and I do not specialize in particle physics, so I might be way off here) is that in a bottle, the neutrons have much lower momenta/momenta which are pointed in much more random directions, which means that when electrons are produced during neutron decay they move away in a random direction, which has a low probability of reaching another baryon and thus a very low probability of being captured by a proton to produce another neutron and apparently slow the neutron decay rate. On the other hand in a beam the momenta are all directed along the beam path, so the electrons are all going to be ejected in roughly the direction of the neutrons in front of them which means a potentially-higher probability of proton capture slowing the neutron decay rate.
At a qualitative level, this seems okay at least to me; the beam decay rate is measured to be slightly slower and the bottle decay rate is slightly faster (because, this conjecture says, proton recapture of emitted electrons results in fewer net neutron decays per unit time in the beam).
I seriously doubt that this is actually related to the problem, because I don’t believe a problem that’s stumped world-class physicists for this long was just solved by little old me, so: is there a canonical way to correct for electron recapture in neutron decay rate experiments, and do such experiments typically use such a corrective factor? By canonical I just mean a way that follows from basic quantum mechanics/has been used before.

Electron capture by protons is not a canonical correction factor in neutron lifetime experiments.
Experimental factors such as differences in neutron detection efficiency and other systematic effects are most likely responsible for the discrepancy in neutron lifetime measurements from beam and bottle methods.
That is interesting reasoning about the neutrons' directional properties, but it doesn't have much impact in the manner that you describe.
To answer your main question: No, experiments measuring neutron lifetime do not typically apply a correction for electron capture in the way you're describing, and it's unlikely that electron capture is a significant factor in explaining the differences between the beam and bottle methods.
Thus, the decay rate is not significantly influenced by the motion of the decay products, and the chance of "reverting" the neutron decay via proton-electron capture is not a major factor in either method as well.

Note that the discrepancy you describe is in measurements of free neutron decay.  For protons and electrons at rest, capture to a free neutron is energetically forbidden.  Because the antineutrino also carries away some energy, electron capture would require a particularly energetic electron to meet a particularly energetic proton.
Then you have dual problems of famously small weak capture cross sections, and impossibly low densities.  A bright cold neutron beamline might have $10^9\text{ neutrons }\rm s^{-1}$.  But that might correspond to only $10^4\ \rm n\ cm^{-3}$, accounting for the neutrons' speed and the size of the beam.  Disclaimer: I coauthored that paper a decade ago, but I have been out of the business a while and I don't quite trust that I'm converting the flux correctly.  But even with an error in the exponent, a tiny fraction of $10^4$ neutrons per cubic centimeter decaying to protons makes for a terribly diffuse proton target.
Finally, keep in mind that neutron confinement is an important part of these experiments.  The cold beam neutrons have milli-eV kinetic energies.  The decay protons have an average energy like 700 eV, and the decay electrons have an average energy like 500 keV.  In the beam experiments, these energetic charged decay products are extracted immediately via magnetic fields which don't steer the uncharged neutrons.  In the bottle experiments the nano-eV neutrons are magnetically trapped, but the traps are not shaped correctly to trap the fast charged particles, which therefore don't linger to interact with each other.
